# C++ stops connecting to DB after so many successful connects

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I am currently using C++ to write directly to a mySQL database, the program will write the first 151 items in the data base but as soon as it gets to number 152 it fails to connect to the data base and throws this exact error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x6188F1F9 (libmysql.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000003B0

I have no idea what this means and cannot seem to find anything on the internet about it. Below I will post the code that writes to the DB. Again though I will say that it is working just fine up until number 152.

```
void writeToDB(string coordString, string time, string id){
MYSQL *connect; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
/* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
{
    fprintf(stderr,"MySQL Initialization Failed");


}
/* Now we will actually connect to the specific database.*/

connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
/* Following if statements are unneeded too, but it's worth it to show on your
first app, so that if your database is empty or the query didn't return anything it
will at least let you know that the connection to the mysql server was established. */

if(connect){
    printf("Connection Succeeded\n");
}
else{
    printf("Connection Failed!\n");
    return;
}
MYSQL_RES *result; /* Create a pointer to recieve the return value.*/
MYSQL_ROW row;  /* Assign variable for rows. */
std::string strSql = "INSERT INTO locationtime (id, dateTime, location) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + time + "','" + coordString + "')";;
const char* sql = strSql.c_str();
mysql_query(connect, sql);
/* Send a query to the database. */

mysql_close(connect);   /* Close and shutdown */


}
```

**EDIT:** Okay so I was able to get it to stop throwing the error, however it is still just mysteriously refusing to connect to the DB, I did test it with a PHP script instead and got 800+ values in the table with no issue at all. Im not sure what the issue is at all!

Comment: Try compiling with diesel or ethanol. :)

Comment: Looks like a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: But seriously, this means that libmysql.dll is throwing an exception.  A very likely cause of this is bad input.  E.g., one of `id`, `time`, etc is empty.  Obviously, you'll want to print out and examine the values that produce the error.

Comment: Once you've fixed this, read up on SQL injection attacks. Putting arbitrary string values directly into SQL statements like this is a very bad idea.

Comment: thanks for the input i will check the variables that i insert to make sure they somehow dont end up null. and as for Mike Seymours suggestion about injections, i do know about them but thanks for the reminder i will make sure to get rid of the characters that can be used for those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `mysql_real_connect()` had failed you should also put a `return;` or `exit(1)` after the `printf("Connection Failed!\n");`:

```
if(connect) {
    printf("Connection Succeeded\n");
}
else {
    printf("Connection Failed!\n");
    return; // <<<
}
```

Otherwise your program will likely crash, without even you could see the error notification printed.
To check what actually was going wrong with the `mysql_real_connect()` function (and maybe give some more useful information than just `"Connection Failed!\n"`), you can use the [`mysql_errno()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-errno.html) function. A list of the error codes relevant for this function can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-connect.html).

Another possibility is you are passing invalid or empty data to the `INSERT` statements. Put some integrity checks for the data passed from `coordString, time, id`.

Comment: i did put the return in there and it no longer crashes but will still mysteriously decide to stop making the connection and thats what i dont get.

Comment: Thanks so much ill let you know what i find. I am letting it run right now to see its output.

Comment: ok now i am very confused.... The errno function is returning a 0... now I'm more than stumped on this one

Comment: @Darksaint2014 There's another one called `mysql_error()`, sorry I'm no MYSQL expert. You should be able to figure out from the doc links I gave, which one actually should be used.

Comment: okay thanks ill keep messing with it and see if i can get it to tell me anything. Ill keep you posted. Thanks for the help

Comment: still can't get anything... it either gives me a code of 0 or nothing at all

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I finally got the answer after I had a second pair of eyes debugging with me.

In my function that actually writes to the database when the connection is actually successful, the `mysql_close();` function was written AFTER the return statements. So it was all on me with a simple error that I over looked many times.

Thanks for all the help from the commenters and the answer I got!